# forecast backward in time

Tags: r, time-series

If I have Time series from 1960 to 2018 and i want to forecast data befor 1960, How I can do it in R?
[image]

Comment: I'm mot saying this is the best way, but how about reversing the order of the time series and forecasting into the future of the reversed time series?

Comment: There might be some logical cut-off point for the past. Like the `AirPassengers` dataset in R, it would be meaningless to predict before 1903. I say this because it seems like you data set is close to 0 around the beginning. Is there a true 0 point for your variable?

Comment: Ok, if my data is AirPassengers dataset in R,how to predict before 1903?

Comment: You wouldn't predict air passengers before 1903 because it is impossible to have them before 1903.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190807/regression-on-default-data-and-backward-extrapolation/190822#190822 suggests that you do exactly what Mark l Stone stated.

Comment: For some code showing how to do it in R, see https://otexts.org/fpp2/backcasting.html

Comment: @IrishStat Great minds thing alike. Although I make no claims to being the first one to think of reversing the time series to, as you say, backcast.